# Can Task Scheduler enter a password for me?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I want Task Scheduler to run a program and start a series of downloads for me before I get in for the day. This program requires a password though. I don't think there's a way to disable this. It's just the password (there isn't even a field for the username). And once that's entered, the program is already configured to automatically begin the download.

Would this simply be the argument, since the prompt is the first thing active in the program? Is this somehow a security issue, even though my computer will be locked the whole time?

Comment: Can you run the program by command line and add, say `/?` to the end , to see if there are any command line switches you can use with the software?

Comment: Nothing different happens when `program.exe/?` runs unfortunately.. :(

Comment: Windows Credential Manager might let you store the password that Task Scheduler wants.

Comment: There's typically a space between exe and /?

Answer (score 1):

Task Scheduler is not capable of entering a password for you. All it does is start a program or script based on a trigger. The trigger can be a time or event.

In order to enter the password, you will need to create a script that does the action. You can then launch the script through Task Scheduler.

If the program does support for the password to be sent as a parameter, then Task Scheduler could do it.

Try running the program from the commandline and append /? to it. (thx Kinnectus)

Answer (score 0):

If the program expects the password in its input, you could run something like:

```
echo password | program
```

Test it first in the Command Prompt.